# How to disable matching if pattern when it comes at the end

Tags: regex, postgresql

I would like to disable matching a pattern if the pattern comes at the end of a line.
For example my string is "Hello, world" and I also want to match this string and "Hello, world!" string.
So far I tried

```
SELECT 'Hello, world' SIMILAR TO '%([\-\,\.\s\?\!]?)world([\-\,\.\s\?\!]+)%', 
       'Hello, world!' SIMILAR TO '%([\-\,\.\s\?\!]?)world([\-\,\.\s\?\!]+)%'
```

But the first match returns false.

**Update**
Words to be matched:
Hello, world!
Good bye, world.
Hi world
This world is amazing.

Words not to be matched:
Helloworld
Hello, worlds.
This problem is considered as worldwide one.

Comment: You said you want to disable matching if the pattern comes at the end, yet in "Hello, world", "world" comes at the end, and you still want the regex to match. Isn't that contradictory?

Comment: @user3409662 but if instead of the word "world" it will be "worlds etc", it will also be matched but I want to prevent it.

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add several examples of strings you want to match, as well as several examples of strings you don't want to match?

Comment: Added words that I want to match and to skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT 'Hello, world' ~* '\yworld\y';
```

`~*` matches a regular expression and is case insensitive

`\y` matches a word boundary

Depending on the value of the standard_conforming_strings parameter, you may have to use 2 backslashes:

```
SELECT 'Hello, world' ~* '\\yworld\\y';
```

Comment: Incredible this worked exactly as I wanted. I have read the docs about ~* sign but surely missed \y addition. Thanks a lot.